# difference between Nginx and node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx

`Nginx` uses an `asynchronous event-driven` approach and `node.js` also uses asynchronous event-driven approach. i know Nginx is a web server while node.js is programming language.

1. what is the key factors that make `Nginx` different than `node.js`?
2. if we run `php(or any web language)` on `Nginx` then how the combo(`PHP(or any web language)+Nginx`) works as `asynchronous event-driven` different than `node.js`?

Answer (score 3):

oh they are indeed completely different, the only common point I guess is that they are both asynchronous event-driven.

Just a few differences:

- Nginx is a web server: it manages HTTP requests, processes them, makes answers. It's written in C, can be extended with modules, can be scripted in Lua. Obviously it can be combined with modules to run PHP or the likes; Then, it's the front door of the application, but the application can be event-driven or not, depending it's architecture. One cool think with nginx is that it's super fast, especially to handle static file requests (image serving for example)
- node.js is NOT a programming language, it's a javascript runtime environment. It can be used to write servers, but other apps too. Those applications have to be written in Javascript, so are indeed asynchronous.